# how to check source code and find out if Android app is native or cross-platfrom

Tags: java, android, mobile

From Android app source code, how to check if the app is purely native app or hybrid.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file... Possible duplicate of this.

Comment: Not at all? That question is about recovering source from an app, this one is about determining if an app has native components.